# Not able to get the value of the button in my controller after postback in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to capture the value of the button in my controller method. I have two buttons save and submit which post back the same form. I need to identify which button was pressed. The buttons are physically present outside the form and use javascript to trigger a postback. The reason why the buttons are out is because of layout reason. I have named the buttons as well as assigned values. Not sure why they are null on postback.  Here is the code

```
<div class="buttonalign" >
    <button name="button" value="submit" onclick="$('#requestHeaderform').submit();" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    <button name="button" value="save"   onclick="$('#requestHeaderform').submit();"  class="btn btn-default">Save as draft</button>

</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Request_Insert", "Request", FormMethod.Post,new { id = "requestHeaderform" }))
{

        <div class="newRequestHeader">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Request/_RequestHeaderView.cshtml")

        </div>
}
```

Controller method

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Request_Insert(NewRequestViewModel newReqeustViewModel,string button)
        {

            switch (button)
            {
                case "submit":
                    // Do something
                    break;
                case "save":
                    // Do something
                    break;
                default:

                    break;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
**View**

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#submit").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            alert($("#submit").attr("value"));
            $('#ButtonHiddenValue').val($("#submit").attr("value"));
            $('#requestHeaderform').submit();
        });
        $("#save").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#ButtonHiddenValue').val($("#save").attr("value"));
            $('#requestHeaderform').submit();
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="buttonalign" >
        <button name="button" id="submit" value="submit"  class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        <button name="button" id="save"  value="save"  class="btn btn-default">Save as draft</button>

    </div>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Request_Insert", "Home", FormMethod.Post,new { id = "requestHeaderform" }))
    {
        <input id="ButtonHiddenValue" name="ButtonHiddenValue" type="hidden"  />

    }
</div>

**Controller**

 public ActionResult Request_Insert(NewRequestViewModel newReqeustViewModel)
        {

            return null;
        }

**Model**

 public class NewRequestViewModel
    {
        public string ButtonHiddenValue { get; set; } 
    }
```

Comment: you mean the name attribute as in my post right. I added your code and the value comes null

Comment: reason is you are keeping your buttons outside the form

Comment: What is the alternative

Comment: U can place a hidden field inside the form. Get which button was clicked in js and set hidden field with button value that was clicked and post.

Comment: You can also use the `form` attribute: `<button type="submit" form="IdOfFormToSubmitOnClick">`. Then, your button may be outside of the form. However, this is not supported in all browsers, and in particular, is not supported in any version of IE. However, you could employ some sort of JS for IE to mimic the behavior by setting a hidden input within the form and submitting the form.

Comment: I have created a hidden field inside the form .   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ButtonHiddenValue)    and then written jquery to assign the hiddenfield. I do see that the value of hiddenfield gets initialised. However on postback in the controller, the value of the hiddenfield in the model is null .    $("#submit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
         $('#ButtonHiddenValue').val($("#submit").attr("value"));
    });

    $("#save").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#ButtonHiddenValue').val($("#save").attr("value"));
    });

Comment: i edited my answer with working solution. give ur buttons id in your code as u are selecting by id. Moreover refer the code above i posted